# redshift select distinct returns repeated values

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a database where each object property is stored in a separate row. The attached query does not return distinct values in a redshift database but works as expected when testing in any mysql compatible database.

```
SELECT DISTINCT distinct_value 
FROM
( 
  SELECT
    uri,
    ( SELECT DISTINCT value_string 
      FROM `test_organization__app__testsegment` AS X 
      WHERE X.uri = parent.uri AND name = 'hasTestString' AND parent.value_string IS NOT NULL ) AS distinct_value 
  FROM `test_organization__app__testsegment` AS parent 
  WHERE     
    uri IN ( SELECT uri 
             FROM `test_organization__app__testsegment` 
             WHERE name = 'types' AND value_uri_multivalue = 'Document'
           )
) AS T 
WHERE distinct_value IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY distinct_value ASC
LIMIT 10000 OFFSET 0
```

Comment: Perhaps the values *look* the same, but there are subtle differences in spacing or the character set.

Comment: Can you provide a sample output? I recommend investigating the cause by simplifying your query (eg removing conditions and nested queries) until `DISTINCT` works as expected. This will likely lead to a reason for the behaviour.

Comment: Chances are the MySQL database is not case sensitive whereas Redshift is.  Try lower(distinct_value) and see if that works.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I got back to the problem today and it seems to be a bug in the redshift. I am going to report it with schema, data and sample queries. While the query above returns repeated values, wrapping it with COUNT and removing order/limit/offset elements returns the correct count of distinct values - really odd.
. Knowing that redshift is partially compatible with postgresql I performed the same tests with local postgresql instance and the results were fine.

Comment: As of March 2017 this still appears to be a bug in RedShift.
I tried a SELECT DISTINCT on an integer field that is the primary key for the table and it brought back duplicates.
On some tables it works fine but on others DISTINCT simply doesn't work so I have had to resort to GROUP BY.

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue as of June 2017

Comment: I still have the problem. Did someone come up with a workaround?

Answer (score 10):

This is not a bug and behavior is intentional, though not straightforward.

In Redshift, you can declare constraints on the tables but Redshift doesn't enforce them, i.e. it allows duplicate values if you insert them. The only difference here is that when you run `SELECT DISTINCT` query against a column that doesn't have a primary key declared it will scan the whole column and get unique values, and if you run the same on a column that has primary key constraint it will just return the output **without performing unique list filtering**. This is how you can get duplicate entries if you insert them.

Why is this done? Redshift is optimized for large datasets and it's much faster to copy data if you don't need to check constraint validity for every row that you copy or insert. If you want you can declare a primary key constraint as a part of your data model but you will need to explicitly support it by removing duplicates or designing ETL in a way there are no such.

More information with specific examples in this Heap blog post [Redshift Pitfalls And How To Avoid Them](https://blog.heapanalytics.com/redshift-pitfalls-avoid/)

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand your answer but I believe that the question was about duplicate data in response, not the fact that the primary key does not enforce uniqueness in Redshift

Comment: @KevinPostlewaite Duplicate data in response comes out because when there is a primary key set on the column Redshift assumes that data is unique and doesn't perform unique filtering when querying `distinct`. How can duplicate data sit in a primary column? because RS doesn't enforce constraints. That's weird but this is how it works.

Comment: Some documentation that supports @AlexYes' answer: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_Defining_constraints.html

Comment: @AlexYes Sorry, I did misunderstand your answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps You can solve this by using appropriate joins.
for example i have duplicate values in table 1 and i want values of table 1 by joining it to table 2 and there is some logic behind joining two tables according to your conditions.

so i can do something like this!!

```
select distinct table1.col1 from table1 left outer join table2 on table1.col1 = table2.col1
```

this worked for me very well and i got unique values from table1 and could remove dublicates