# Redshift SQL JOIN behaves different for one ID and and different when we have more than one ID in predicate?

Tags: sql, join, amazon-redshift

I can not share the data and the table details, hence to replicate the issue, here are test tables with sample data. Table 'table1' has 14 total rows with 10 unique rows for 'column1' values 'id1', and 12 total rows with 8 unique rows for ID 'id2'.
'table2' has 1 row each for 'column1' values 'id1', and 'id2'.

NOTE: The issue is **not reproducible** by these test tables. In fact, after recreation of actual tables where I'm seeing this issue, I get correct join result.
At the moment, I reckon something has changed behind the scene in the redshift because of this I'm seeing this issue. I'll update once I hear more.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table1 (
column1 varchar(255) encode lzo,
t1column2 varchar(255) encode lzo,
t1column3 varchar(255) encode lzo,

PRIMARY KEY(column1))
distkey(column1)
sortkey(column1);

COMMIT;

----------------------------------

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table2 (
column1 varchar(255) encode lzo,
t2column2 varchar(255) encode lzo,
t2column3 varchar(255) encode lzo,
);

COMMIT;

----------------------------------

insert into table1 values
('id1', '0', 'a'),
('id1', '0', 'a'),
('id1', '0', 'a'),
('id1', '0', 'a'),
('id1', '1', 'a'),
('id1', '1', 'a'),
('id1', '2', 'a'),
('id1', '3', 'a'),
('id1', '4', 'a'),
('id1', '5', 'a'),
('id1', '6', 'a'),
('id1', '7', 'a'),
('id1', '8', 'a'),
('id1', '9', 'a'),
('id2', '0', 'a'),
('id2', '0', 'a'),
('id2', '1', 'a'),
('id2', '2', 'a'),
('id2', '3', 'a'),
('id2', '4', 'a'),
('id2', '5', 'a'),
('id2', '6', 'a'),
('id2', '7', 'a'),
('id2', '7', 'a'),
('id2', '7', 'a'),
('id2', '7', 'a');

-------------------------

insert into table2 values
('id1', null, 'pqr'),
('id2', null, 'xyz'),
```

CASE 1: Query with 2 ids gives 1 row each per column1 value i.e. 'id1' and 'id2'. Here, I'm expecting 10 rows for 'id1' and 8 rows for 'id2'.

```
select distinct t1.column1, t1.t1column2, t1.t1column3, t2.t2column2, t2.t2column3 
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 
on t1.column1=t2.column1
where t1.column1 IN ('id1', 'id2');
```

CASE 2: Same query when executed with only 1 value 'id1' gives correct 10 unique rows as expected.

```
select distinct t1.column1, t1.t1column2, t1.t1column3, t2.t2column2, t2.t2column3 
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 
on t1.column1=t2.column1
where t1.column1 IN ('id1');
```

Removed CASE 3 and CASE 4 to avoid confusion.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194342/discussion-on-question-by-tyro-redshift-sql-join-behaves-different-for-one-id-an).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [redshift select distinct returns repeated values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32875895/redshift-select-distinct-returns-repeated-values)

Comment: Your data violates your constraints. Redshift uses query algorithms that assume they don't. So your query results are whatever garbage that happens to produce. You cannot use Redshift under those conditions & trust results. See the answers at the duplicate link. Declare constraints that describe your data. PS You still haven't fixed unclear & wrong language I mentioned in the chat comments.

Answer (score 0):

It was wrong in first place to have primary key constraint on table where we knew there won't be unique values for that primary key field even though we thought redshift doesn't enforce it in the same way for foreign or unique key constraints.

During ETL, one needs to ensure that the data we load into a primary key column is unique otherwise we should not define such a column as a primary key.

If we just change to the query like (trim() on primary key column), it would return the correct results because in this case we would be forcing the optimizer to ignore the primary key.

Reason we didn't see this issue before because the query optimizer wasn't taking primary key into considerations in my CASE 1.

Lately, in one of the redshift updates some time in late March, query optimizer has started to take more advantage of primary key in order to improve query performance after which issue had started.

So, solution in my case is to remove primary key constraint on the table, and the query remains the same.